# Idle current flow in movesense

Tags: movesense

Does unsubscribing the sensors from mobile application Movesense showcase app, completely disable the sensors and they are no more in idle state and do not consume idle current. 
Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

The sensors have power routed to them but they are not running if there are no subscriptions. The power consumption in that case is really minimal as can be seen from the usual 9uA IDLE power consumption in [the power consumption documentation](http://movesense.com/docs/system/power_consumption/).